# Get rows matching criterion from all sheets in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google spreadsheet with about 20 sheets (each with a proper name, not `Sheet1`,`Sheet2` etc) of the following structure -

```
Task Title  |  Description  |  Status  |  Comments1  |  Comments 2
------------------------------------------------------------------
Task1       |      Xyz      | Stage 1  |             |
Task2       |      Xyz      | Stage 2  |  abc        |
Task3       |      Xyz      | Done     |             |
Task4       |               | Done     |             |
```

How do I create a new sheet with the same structure of above for all tasks (across sheets) that have `Status` as `Done`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new sheet into your workbook and use this formula (replacing Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 with your actual sheet names):

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:C;Sheet2!A:C;Sheet3!A:C},"where Col3='Done'")`

Within the  {  } you will need to add in the A:C reference for each indiviual sheet separated by ;

To return the header row as well, add a 1 to the end of the query:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:E;Sheet2!A:E;Sheet3!A:E},"where Col3='Done'",1)`

Or to return individual columns, you can include a select statment:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:E;Sheet2!A:E;Sheet3!A:E},"select Col1 where Col3='Done'",1)`

Comment: this does not seem to work when the filtering column is not the last column. I have edited the question to reflect what my data looks like better.

Comment: the number of columns shouldn't matter, as long as you are searching for 'Done' in the correct column number of the dataset.  I set up an example sheet: https://goo.gl/CN5S7Y

Comment: The formula works for the example I have give, but **does not seem to work for my specific data - have no idea why**. The issue is that the each cell in the first row of the result has all the matching rows of `Sheet1` (the first sheet in the formula) i.e. the first cell for the above example would read `Task Title Task3 Task4`. Then a proper result is seen in the rows below.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more example formulae